# Laravel 5.5 image storage asset() helper config

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have images in `storage/app/` trying to access them with `{{asset('about.jpg')}}`. The path that is returned == `test.com/about.jpg` but the image resides in `test.com/storage/about.jpg`. Should I change the `{{asset('storage/about.jpg')}}` or is there a filesystem issue I am not seeing? TY

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk) try linking your directory by using `php artisan storage:link`
 
and then you can access your file like `{{asset('about.jpg')}}`

Comment: I linked the storage, as above the path is wrong, it is /about.jpg but to access the image it is at storage/about.

Comment: What do you mean "it is at storage/about"? Once you create the symbolic link, accessing files at storage acts exactly like accessing them from /public/. For example: /storage/something.jpg can be accessed at /something.jpg .